# Suppressing user updates when using the geemap.ee_export_image function in GEE Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I am exporting GEE files to my local machine through the `geemap` Python API using the following code:

```
# download 30m SRTM data
SRTM30 = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');
filename = os.path.join(OUTpath, 'DEM_'+domain+'.tif');
geemap.ee_export_image(SRTM30, filename=filename, scale=sm_resolution, region=my_domain, crs = epsg_code);
```

The `geemap.ee_export_image` function outputs the following user updates each time it exports an image:

[image]

I am exporting a large number of files so I am wondering if there is a way to suppress these user updates so my cron job confirmation email is not so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. You could [submit a ticket](https://github.com/giswqs/geemap/issues) asking for a verbose parameter to be added to the function.

As a workaround, you could [redirect `sys.stdout` temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37989355/737471):

```
import contextlib
# etc...
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    geemap.ee_export_image(SRTM30, filename=filename, scale=sm_resolution, region=my_domain, crs = epsg_code)
```

Or if you are going to use `geemap.ee_export_image` more than once in your script, you could wrap it into a function

```
import contextlib
# etc...

def ee_export_image(*args, **kwargs):
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
        geemap.ee_export_image(*args, **kwargs)

# etc...

ee_export_image(SRTM30, filename=filename, scale=sm_resolution, region=my_domain, crs = epsg_code)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!